# Is there any disadvantage to CS_DBLCLKS?

Tags: windows, winapi, event-handling, double-click

Unlike other mouse events, double-click events are optional in Windows. A window does not receive double-click events unless developer specifically
opts in to receive them ([by registering window class with CS_DBLCLKS style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/mouse-clicks#double-clicks)).

I'm wondering why that is? Is there a performance or compatibility penalty when enabling double-click detection, and that's why this setting is optional? Or is it just a historic remnant that is not relevant anymore?

Basically, my question is, is there any disadvantage to enabling this style for all windows in an application?

Comment: The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/mouse-clicks#double-clicks) you provided explains exactly the reason. If you don't need double clicks and you opt in for double clicks anyway, you will receive a `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` when you double click instead of two `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` messages.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks. Now that you explain it it's so obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

@Jabberwocky points out that the link provided in the question gives the reason. To receive `DBLCLK` messages, register the window class to receive them.

Taking a deliberate decision to register or not for `DBLCLK` messages is useful depending on the target application.

For mouse-operated applications, some sort of double-click functionality is common. Register for and process these messages.

However, touchscreen applications are operated by a stubby human finger and give inconsistent results depending on who operates the touchscreen. In addition, several Windows registry settings affect mouse sensitivity in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`:

```
DoubleClickHeight (default = 4 on Windows 10)
DoubleClickWidth (default = 4)
DoubleClickSpeed (default = 500)
```

`Width` and `Height` refer to how far apart (in pixels) clicks are allowed to be to be considered "double-clicks". Too far away, and two rapid clicks are not a double-click. If double-click functionality is required on a touchscreen, `Width` and `Height` would be increased.

`Speed` refers to the time (in ms) between clicks to be considered a double-click, provided both clicks are within the area defined by `Width` and `Height`.

Touchscreen applications are usually dedicated to a single application (like an embedded point-of-sale kiosk). They will generally give unreliable double-click functionality and should normally avoid trying to. The embedded Windows system might be configured (see the registry settings above) to allow some use of double-clicks outside of the main application. But the application itself would not register (or use) double-clicks at all.